# How to insert value in console of eclipse using java code

Tags: java

I want to enter value in console at run-time (during execution), rather than hard code it manually. I have following code:

```
System.out.println("Open the following URL and grant access to your account:");
System.out.println(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
String authURL=requestToken.getAuthorizationURL();
//Generate a pin number from auth url by login to twitter account.
String pinNum=GenratePIN_LoginTwitter.accessTokenForTwitter(authURL);
System.out.print("Enter the PIN(if aviailable) or just hit enter.[PIN]:");
String pin =br.readLine();
```

Here I want to insert the value of 'pinNum' in console and proceed with the next steps.Please suggest regarding it.

Comment: you mean you want the input from user..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the input from the user from console use `java.util.Scanner` class

```
 System.out.println("Enter a number: ")
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int i = sc.nextInt();
 System.out.println("The number is: "+i);
```

The above code will help you to get the input from console

For more on `Scanner` refer [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basically **System.in** is The **standard input stream**.this stream corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by the host environment or user.
so you can use it in some of the java IO API.as @abhishek told for Scanner you can also use below code.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = br.readLine();
```